# How to make a div align with a specific td on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Please look here too see what I am looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w4NB.png)

[The TD element I am trying to align with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTvC3.png)

If you look at the pictures above you will see the pop up box that appears if someone incorrectly types an email in the 'assistant email:' field.

I want to align that div (with the error text) with that assistant email input field so that the left side of the div aligns with the left side of the input field. But can't seem to figure out how to do that. I am working within an environment that creates these fields for me and places them inside a table like format. Each label and field is in its own `td` and each row is inside a `tr`.

In this case I am using javascript like this:

```
$("#" + emailToValidate).parents('tr').after('<div id="a_email" class="email"></div>');

$("#a_email").css({
  "position":"relative",
  "padding":"13px",
  "margin":"15px 0 0.5em",
  "width":"300px",
  "color":"#D35400",
  "background":"#D35400",
  "-webkit-border-radius":"0px",
  "-moz-border-radius":"0px",
  "border-radius":"0px", 
  "vertical-align": "top"
});
```

Here is the HTML of that section:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" id="last_name_label" width="12.5%" scope="col">
Last Name:
<span class="required">*</span>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="37.5%">
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" size="30" maxlength="100" value="Test" title="">
</td><td valign="top" id="assistant_email_c_label" width="12.5%" scope="col">
Assistant Email:
</td>
<td valign="top" width="37.5%">
<input type="text" name="assistant_email_c" id="assistant_email_c" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" title="">
</td></tr>
```

The the `div` element which is not inside a table-row itself is immediately after the code right above this text.

```
<div id="a_email" class="email" style="position: relative; padding: 13px; margin: 15px 0px 0.5em; width: 300px; color: rgb(211, 84, 0); border-radius: 0px; vertical-align: top; background: rgb(211, 84, 0);">
<h4 align="left">
<font color="white">Please format the email as such: <b>'youremail@emailprovider.com'</b>.<br>The save button will remain disabled <br>until corrections are made.
</font>
</h4>
</div>
```

I need to align this `div` WITHOUT changing other elements on the page. I am simply needing to add something to that css in the javascript that would align it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle with the contraint to not touch the HTML structure and do it with CSS and JS :

[See this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz7L7r6h/10/)

**CSS**

```
#a_email { 
  display: none;
  position :absolute !important;
  left: 0; 
  top: 20px;
  padding:13px;
  margin:15px 0 0.5em;
  width:300px;
  color:#D35400;
  background:#D35400;
  -webkit-border-radius:0px;
  -moz-border-radius:0px;
  border-radius:0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wrap { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
```

**JS **

```
$(function(){
    $('#assistant_email_c').blur(function(){
    if(validateEmail($(this).val()) == false ){
            $("#a_email").insertAfter($(this)).addClass('toWrap');
            $(this).addClass('toWrap');
      if($('.wrap').length == 0){
        $('.toWrap').wrapAll( "<div class='wrap' />" );
      }
      $("#a_email").css('display','inline-block').fadeIn(300);
    }else{
      $("#a_email").fadeOut(300);
    }
  });
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```